# How can I use source maps with gulp?

Tags: javascript, gulp, minify, source-maps

How can I use source maps with gulp ?

```
...
sourcemaps  = require('gulp-sourcemaps'),
concat      = require('gulp-concat'),
uglify      = require('gulp-uglify'),
...

gulp.task('concat-all-js', function() {
    return gulp
        .src([
            'app/app.js',
            'app/**/*.js'
        ])
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(concat('app.js'))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(rename({
            suffix: '.min'
        }))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/'));
});
```

I add two file : app.min.js and app.min.js.map

But when I put an error in my file app.min.js, my source maps does'nt work.

I have activate the option in my browser (Chrome), but I always see this error :

```
ReferenceError: blabla is not defined
    at Object.formModel (http://localhost/dist/app.min.js:1:23964)
```

My files are the same folder '**/dist**'.

I see this line in my app.min.js (last line) :

```
//# sourceMappingURL=app.min.js.map
```

Comment: It's a mistake in my code. I renamed 'Form' (true value) by 'blabla' (false value, to have an error)

Comment: Ah, I see the problem now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like an error in your code causing Gulp to bomb out, not anything to do with sourcemaps, per se. You probably just need to improve how you handle errors appearing. Try replacing:

```
.pipe(uglify())
```

With:

```
.pipe(uglify(uglifyOptions).on('error', function(uglify) {
        console.error(uglify.message);
        console.error("Line "+uglify.lineNumber);
        this.emit('end');
    }))
```

At the moment, if there's an error in your code, is causing Gulp to exit.

(Unless you have some error handling code not shown.)

Comment: I don't see the name of the file that contains the error